# Show: if $x \in A'$, then $x \in (A \setminus \{x\})'$ in Hausdorff space; dash denotes limit points

Tags: general-topology

EDIT: It was pointed out I managed to misstate the question. Sorry, and thanks to Daniel Fischer for pointing it out.

RTP: Letting $B'$ be the set of limit points of $B$ for any set $B$, show that if $x \in A'$, then $x \in (A \setminus \{x\})'$ in a Hausdorff space.

My attempt: Let $x \in A'$. Then for any open $U$ containing $x$ we have $(U \setminus \{x\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. We want to show that this implies that for any open $V$ containing $x$ we have $(V \setminus \{x\}) \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$ so that $x \in (A \setminus \{x\})'$.

I can see that the trick is going to be using the first separation axiom to show that $U \setminus \{x\}$ is open if $U$ is open. But I can't see why I need that: surely $(V \setminus \{x\}) \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) = (V \setminus \{x\}) \cap A$ and so we can set $U = V$ and thus immediately have the equality between the sets of limit points without utilizing the fact that the space is Hausdorff?

Comment: You need to show that $y\in A' \iff y \in (A\setminus\{x\})'$. You can't say "Let $x\in A'$" and only ever look at $x$ if $x$ is the special point that is removed from $A$.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake in trying to write the question more concisely. The exercise actually states to show that $x \in A' \iff x \in (A \setminus \{x\})'$. I've edited the question to correct.

Comment: Okay. What's the definition of limit point you're using? That for all neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ you shall have $(U\setminus \{x\}) \cap A \neq \varnothing$? $U\cap (A\setminus \{x\}) \neq \varnothing$? $U\cap A \not\subset \{x\}$? All these are easily seen to be equivalent, and the equivalence $x\in A' \iff x \in (A\setminus \{x\})'$ holds for all topological spaces with any of these definitions.

Comment: The first one of these. So you are saying I do not need the fact that we are in a Hausdorff Space? Then I think I understand what's going on, cheers :) (though still confused why the question mentioned it)

Comment: Yes, no need for Hausdorffness. $(U\setminus \{x\}) \cap A = (U\setminus \{x\}) \cap (A \setminus \{x\})$. Probably the poser of the exercise thought of ($\omega$-)accumulation points. In a Hausdorff ($T_1$ suffices) space, every limit point is an $\omega$-accumulation point. On the other hand, it is clear that an $\omega$-accumulation point of $A$ is also one of $A\setminus \{x\}$ (and vice versa) for every $x$.